# Adjacency matrix and recognizing hierarchy?

Tags: graphs, adjacency-matrix

I'm currently learning about graphs and I have some questions regarding adjacency matrices. Given an arbitrary adjacency matrix:

[image]

Is there any way to tell if that matrix represents a hierarchal graph structure? Obviously in the above case it's not.

Something like:

[image]

I know the rows of and `i x i`  adjacency matrix represent the out-degree of `i`th vertex and columns represent the in-degree of the `i`th vertex. But is there any way to tell just by looking at the general structure of the adjacency matrix if the graph is hierarchical (At least, for smaller matrices as above) ?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you give a self-contained definition of what a "hierarchical graph structure" is?  Do you mean a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) (or forest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition you can check if a graph is a tree (regardless of its representation) with these facts:

1. The graph does not have cycles.
2. It only has a single connected component.

The first condition can be checked with a simple [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) checking if there is a [back edge](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall11/rec/rec14.pdf). The connected components can be counted using either DFS or BFS.

Regarding to an adjacency matrix, every tree is a bipartite graph. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89692/if-graph-is-tree-what-can-be-said-about-its-adjacency-matrix), but keep in mind that proving that a a graph is bipartite does not mean it is a tree.